# Can I translate Job 6:14 as …

Tags: translation-philosophy, job

I see that there are different translations of this verse. All did not seem to be satisfying. So I was wondering could it be possible to translate it as:

> “To the one in despair his friends [withheld] kindness and [told] he
> [the one in despair] abandoned the fear of the Lord.”

Comment: As proposed, I find your reading unintelligible. Perhaps you could provide some punctuation? Also, shall I assume you are working from an interlinear?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best translation of Job 6:14?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13647/what-is-the-best-translation-of-job-614)

Answer (score 1):

Job 6:14 is frustratingly terse - in the Hebrew it is only six words!  It reads literally:

> To the despairing friend - kindness and fear [of the?] almighty [he]
> forsakes

Ellicott summarizes the difficulty in translating this verse:

> (14) But he forsaketh the fear of the Almighty.—It is difficult to
> determine the precise relation of dependent clauses in an archaic
> language like the Hebrew; but the Authorised Version is, at all
> events, not correct here, the sense rather being, “Even to one that
> forsaketh the fear of the Almighty;” or, perhaps, better still, “lest
> he should forsake;” or, “he may even forsake,” &c.

The common versions have translations that can be grouped into three categories:

1. ESV & NIV: He who withholds kindness from a friend forsakes the fear of the Almighty.
2. BSB * NKJV: A despairing man should have the kindness of his friend, even if he forsakes the fear of the Almighty.
3. NASB & AB: “For the despairing man there should be kindness from his friend; So that he does not abandon the fear of the Almighty.

That is, we must decide, based on the single verb "forsakes":

- whether the friend or the despairing man is its subject
- whether forsaking the Almighty is conditional or compensatory or absolute.

Even the context is little help here.  Thus, Job 6:14 reads more like a proverb than a line of poetry.

Thus, no final conclusion is possible.  For what it is worth, I prefer the NASB translation, but I do not insist upon it.

Comment: + 1 and thanks for the lesson in biblical Hebrew. However, I think the context is more helpful than you indicate.  6:14 is the start of a section bemoaning Job's treatment by his friends,  but he is not in danger of abandoning fear of God. (6:4 - 'the terrors of God are arrayed against me.') So I think the ESV and NIV have it right..

Answer (score 0):

Your translation as stands is obscure.

The Hebrew text of Job 6:14 is as follows:

לַמָּ֣ס מֵרֵעֵ֣הוּ חָ֑סֶד וְיִרְאַ֖ת שַׁדַּ֣י יַעֲזֽוֹב׃
lammās mērēʿēhû ḥāsed, wəyirʾat šadday yaʿăzôb

I prefer to interpret Job as saying that failing to be compassionate to others is equivalent to turning away from God's fear; that is, it is equivalent to having no reverence for God. According to this viewpoint, the person who has no love for a friend also has no respect for God. The use of the third person may be confusing to translators.

This is a good book to help with translating Job.

Reyburn, Wiliam. A Handbook on Job. New York: UBS, 1992